# User gets error 400 on intranet sites only

Tags: intranet, 400

I had the user log into multiple machines on different domains, both virtual and physical, and the issue persists. When I log into those same machines I get to the sites without issue. I checked the users group membership in AD and he has all of our baseline groups plus the ones he needs for his job...
No other users are reporting this issue.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what the names resolve to, whether you're using a proxy, or anything else that might help troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was Token Bloat. The user was in 325 groups in Active Directory and his token was over 12,000k causing a Kerberos error. Removed unneeded AD groups to fix.